# JSON with Chinese characters processing to XML in java for RDB

Tags: java, xml, json, weibo

Im doing a RESTful webservice call on the Chinese weibo platform and get a JSON file in return that looks like this:

```
[{
"id": 2098220080,
"idstr": "2098220080",
"class": 1,
"screen_name": "王理巍", .....}]
```

So its an array with 100 inner objects. My aim is to import these data into a relational database (SAP HANA). As I can only import files in XML or csv format, I think the best approach is to parse the JSON into XML with some small java app.
Ive already tried different JSON parsing libraries but there seems to be a problem with the array. So I chose the Apache json.org lib and call the webservice via InputStream.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

String date, userName = null, text, gender, city, location, province;
int userId = 0, statusId;
URL url = null;

    try {
    url = new URL("https://api.weibo.com/2/suggestions/users/hot.json?client_id=1637521539&access_token=2.00xusAWD0YuxsZ10f9689fa7sIoHJC&category=auto");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//Call URL as InputStream
try (InputStream is = url.openStream();
    JsonReader rdr = Json.createReader(is)) {

    JsonArray results = rdr.readArray();

    //System.out.println(results.toString());

    JsonObject[] objects = new JsonObject[100];
    JsonObject o1 = results.getJsonObject(0);
    //System.out.println(o1);

    //Read each element
    try {
    userId = o1.getInt("id");
    userName = o1.getString("name");
    province = o1.getString("province");
    city = o1.getString("city");
    location = o1.getString("location");
    gender = o1.getString("gender");
    date = o1.getString("created_at");
    statusId = o1.getInt("id");
    text = o1.getString("text");
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        System.out.println("No value");
    }

    //Build XML
    String xmlString = XML.toString(userId,"id");
    xmlString = XML.toString(userName, "name");
```

In this snippet I only read one object for testing purposes without any automation. Basically Im dealing with 2 issues here now.

First: The elements containing Chinese simplified characters are displayed as ???
Second: How can I append several elements to the XML-String?

I really appreciate your hints concerning my questions and also some general ideas for a probable better solution.

Comment: Ok the first problem is already solved. I had to change the Encoding in Eclipse Run configuration to UTF-8.

Comment: Therefore Im facing another issue: Does somebody know how to differentiate between the status id and the user id? Both attributes are named "id". Thats a main issue because status id will be the PK in the database later

Comment: How to deal with the chinese character issue if working on java transformation in informatica and not eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright problems solved.

In case ur interested: To access the nested "status" element in one object, just use

```
JsonObject status = o1.getJsonObject("status");
```

For appending several objects I used the StringBuilder method.